# Metor: save html as string and later convert it to a DOM node

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I would like to save a string like "`<div class='some_class'>some content</div>`", in a **mongo** document, and later, when I fetch this content, I want to convert it into a DOM node.

How can I edit the content before adding it to the DOM and convert it to a DOM node using meteor?

Comment: You can take a look at [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) - it is a Node package for manipulating DOM on the server-side. A Meteorized version of the same can be found [here](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/cheerio).

Comment: I'm pretty sure a string like "some content", will never be "DOM". You would need to wrap it in some HTML tag for it to be "DOM"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @blaze-sahlzen you can use [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for the manipulation of the `HTML`. But after all, it's just a `String` that you can also modify with the usual [methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_strings_object.htm).

To show the `HTML`, I suggest you look into `{{{triple braces}}}` - they can be used to include raw `HTML` within your page. You should use these cautiously and make sure the `HTML` content is safe and free from syntax errors. Be very sure to sanitize (escape/clean) the `HTML` before you store it in mongo!

If it is a whole template that you wanna render, there is an API for it [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_render).